# Analytics content from Android does not appear on Google Analytics web site

Tags: android, google-analytics

Can't understand what's the problem. I registered account at https://www.google.com/analytics/, loaded the lib, deployed sample project from zip where lib was in. Then pointed out libs path and added my analytics id to tracker in format "UA-11111-1" and setup debug mode. In logcat I can see that all my events are handled and analytics server respond with "200 OK". But on the anlytics web page there no any information and data about events.

Comment: Google Analytics is not a real time tool. Data can take up to 48 hours to show up.